# About limiting checkbox base on value in textbox

Tags: php

can anyone help me with limiting checkbox based on the number that in the textbox? For example, I have 3 textboxes 
textbox1,
textbox2, 
textbox3total

For example, I input 3 in textbox1 and 2 in textbox2, which result in textbox3total= 5.

Based on the value of textbox3 which is 5, only number 5 I can check on my checkbox which is the limit, the limit is based on the number in total in textbox3.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: can't figure out what you actually want to achieve?

Comment: this is my textbox so the total hold here
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="TotalTickets" id="TotalTickets" readonly value=""/>
                                                  

and this is my checkbox example                                                                
  <input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" id="1A" value="1A"/>

Answer (score 0):

user javascript ir jquery for example

```
//get the value of textbox 3
var txt5 = $("#textbox5").val();
var check = 0;

//make single class for checkbox and use it
$(".classCheckbox").on('click',function(){
//get number of checkbox check
check = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
if(check >= txt5){ 
 alert("The Limit is " + txt5);
return false;
}
})
```

Comment: this is my textbox so the total hold here
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="TotalTickets" id="TotalTickets" readonly value=""/>
                                                  

and this is my checkbox example                                                                
  <input type="checkbox" name="seat[]" id="1A" value="1A"/>